# babel react issues finding modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, reactjs

I have a small react jsx file that needs to be compiled to js.

I install babel and the presets like so in the directory with the js file

```
npm -g install babel-cli

npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

My script does this

```
babel --presets es2015,react input.js -o output.js
```

Everything works.

Reboot the machine and re-run the build. It fails.

Each time I reinstall babel and the presets to get it to work.

I am not a js dev and looking up the similar questions list and a google search for this issue returns 25 different ways of "fixing" the issue. This seems like a basic task, why is there so much noise around it and what is the right way to add this to a larger non-javascript build process .

Comment: try installing presets using --save as: npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react --save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the `preset`s globally.

Do this

1. Create a new folder and move you `input.js` to that folder
2. Do `npm init`
3. Do `npm i babel` without `-g`
4. Do `npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react`
5. Open the console at that location
6. Run `./node_mudules/.bin/babel --presets es2015,react input.js -o output.js`

Comment: I am just following instructions here - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/language-tooling.html Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes. That is if you have project folder setup properly. Try my solution.

Comment: I tried it. Got Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory ".". What does "project folder setup properly" involve?

Comment: @Sharun Updated the answer!

Comment: It works. Also after reboot. But not clear to me which version of babel and the presets are being used. I have 13 MB of files now in this new node_modules folder. Step 3 had to use babel-cli. Step 6 worked with just babel. My question is what have I actually done here to convert the jsx to js? Do I need to create a npm prackage and create this package.json to get this done? And thanks a lot for your time. Much appreciated.